# How to align MultiView with TreeView in asp.net web forms?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, css-float, alignment

I want to have a tree view on the left side of the screen along with a multiview which displays the content of the selected tree item on the right side of the screen. My problem is that I cannot seem to align the multiview such that it is to the right of the tree view. Its stuck to the bottom of the treeview. Here's a simplified version of what I have.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="1" Value="1">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="1.1" Value="1.1"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="1.2" Value="1.2"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="2" Value="2"></asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>

    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="something here"></asp:Label>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

How do I align it to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put both inside two `div's` and use css-style `float:left` for the first and `float:right` for the second with width it will work.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="float:left;width:200px;">

    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="1" Value="1">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="1.1" Value="1.1"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="1.2" Value="1.2"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="2" Value="2"></asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; width:800px;">
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="something here"></asp:Label>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity...you can wrap them both (treeview and multiview) inside a div. Then you can style the divs to dipplay inline-block...That'll give you the results you want

Hope it helps

leo